# Google Maps API not loading due to window.handleApiReady is not a function error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a problem with using the Google Maps API.

One page load is get the error `window.handleApiReady is not a function`, where it most certainly is. Looking at the code below you can see I use it as a callback function:

```
    /**
    * Load GoogleMaps API
    */
    $(function(){
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=handleApiReady';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });

    /**
         * Show map once GoogleMaps API is ready
         */
    function handleApiReady() {     
        if ( $("#map_canvas").length > 0 ) {                
            var latlng = $("#store_lat_long").html();
            var details = latlng.split(',');
            initialize(Number(details[0]), Number(details[1]), 'map_canvas');
        }
    }
```

Sticking an `alert` or `console.log` out on the first line of `handleApiReady` shows that it doesn't seem to find the function. Why would that be?

Comment: is handleApiReady really global (the same as window.handleApiReady).

Comment: it works fine. is this part of a userscript? in that case, probably a `@grant` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused with the code I provided being located in a `document.ready`. Moving it outside of the `document.ready` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks wrong with that code and I do not get an error. Your error must be caused by somewhere else.

http://jsbin.com/adakuc/1/edit